# How to add foreign-key column to dj-stripe admin?

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I would like to add plan names to [dj-stripe](https://dj-stripe.dev/dj-stripe/) django admin so I can see a readable name for what each subscription is associated with. Adding "cancel_at" worked, but I can't use the name of a Product from a Plan.

In my_app\admin.py I do this:

```
from djstripe.models import Subscription
from djstripe.admin import StripeModelAdmin, SubscriptionItemInline

...

class SubscriptionAdmin(StripeModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("plan__product__name", "customer", "status", "cancel_at")
    list_filter = ("status", "cancel_at_period_end")
    list_select_related = ("customer", "customer__subscriber")
    inlines = (SubscriptionItemInline,)
    def _cancel(self, request, queryset):
        """Cancel a subscription."""
        for subscription in queryset:
            subscription.cancel()

    _cancel.short_description = "Cancel selected subscriptions"  # type: ignore # noqa
    actions = (_cancel,)


admin.site.unregister(Subscription)
admin.site.register(Subscription, SubscriptionAdmin)

...
```

Which produces this error:

> Subscription has no field named 'plan__product__name'

How do I add extra columns in dj-stripe that require foreign key lookups?

Comment: Can you test this?  Verify you can currently traverse those relationships?  Like so
`sub = Subscription.objects.first(); 
print(sub.plan.product.name)`.  I would test out a few different approaches in the `python manage.py shell` interface to be sure I could get the data I want and verify the expected relationship behavior.

Comment: yes, with a breakpoint in my admin.py I get the string I want back from Subscription.objects.first().plan.product.name

Comment: I suspect the `first()` part is your problem.  I don't think you can use string field references for the `Many` side of a `OneToMany` relationship. This is not dj-stripe specific but more Django models in general:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: Pity. What if I somehow overrode the __str__ method of the djstripe Subscription model? Would be just as good to see the plan_product_name as the hyperlinked label in the first column of admin.

Comment: That is definitely an option.  I think it would still hyperlink since that is a function of the default Django admin page.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: any tips on doing this? I tried making a new class called CustomSubscription, overriding the str method, and registering that instead of Subscription, but it doesn't show up in admin.

Comment: You would need to register them with the admin site.  I'm not sure if `dj-stripe` has any custom ModelAdmin classes but you can see how to do this with standard Django models here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial02/#introducing-the-django-admin

Comment: I am registering them, using the approach in the question. But when I register my custom model with the overridden str method, then it doesnt show up in admin. Reading the django docs on how to register a new model from stratch doesn't help me understand why this override method isn't working for djstripe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to make a callable then reference it in the modeladmin class.

Per the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display):

> ModelAdmin.list_display
>
> Set list_display to control which fields are displayed on the change list page of the admin.
>
> There are four types of values that can be used in list_display. All but the simplest may use the display() decorator is used to
> customize how the field is presented:
>
> A callable that accepts one
> argument, the model instance. For example:

```
@admin.display(description='Name')
    def upper_case_name(obj):
        return ("%s %s" % (obj.first_name, obj.last_name)).upper()

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (upper_case_name,)
```

Which means in my case I can do this to add a combined tier + interval column:

```
@admin.display(description='Subscription Tier and Interval')
def subscription_tier_interval(obj):
    return ("%s - %s" % (obj.plan.product.name, obj.plan.interval))


class SubscriptionAdmin(StripeModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("customer", "status", subscription_tier_interval, "cancel_at")
    list_filter = ("status", "cancel_at_period_end")
    list_select_related = ("customer", "customer__subscriber")
    inlines = (SubscriptionItemInline,)
    def _cancel(self, request, queryset):
        """Cancel a subscription."""
        for subscription in queryset:
            subscription.cancel()

    _cancel.short_description = "Cancel selected subscriptions"  # type: ignore # noqa
    actions = (_cancel,)

admin.site.unregister(Subscription)
admin.site.register(Subscription, SubscriptionAdmin)
```